# NullPointerException while using adapter.getItem(position)

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have the following code in **WeekDays.java**

```
ArrayAdapter<TaskInAWeek> adapter1 = (ArrayAdapter<TaskInAWeek>) getListAdapter() ;
TaskInAWeek taski;
ArrayList<Long> checkedItms = new ArrayList<Long>();
ArrayList<Long> uncheckedItms = new ArrayList<Long>();

    for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++)
    {
        Log.i("value's size:" +values.size()," ");
        if(EditStatusAdapter.tog==1)
        {
            Log.i("i::"+i," ");
                taski = adapter1.getItem(i);
                long id = taski.getId();
                Log.i("nid:"+id," ");
                checkedItms.add(id);
            }
        else 
        {
            Log.i("i::"+i," ");
            taski = adapter1.getItem(i);
            long id = taski.getId();
            Log.i("nid:"+id," ");
            uncheckedItms.add(id);
        }
    }
```

Its custom Array Adapter is EditStatusAdapter.java. I get a `NullPointerException` at this pt`taski = adapter1.getItem(i);`.

I have used similar one in one of my activity but it did work fine. I guess its due to the custom array adapter. But I could not ignore it as well. Can anyone tel me how to clear the exception?

Comment: is adapter1 a valid object ? Have you checked that adapter1 is not equals to null?

Comment: Any chance of `adapter1` being Null at this position?

Comment: I din't check! But how can I do it?

Comment: it will be null initially.. but then it chouldn't be null when taski=adapter1.getItem(i);. Are there any other posibilities ?